# How to implement `lookup` in 2nd level in mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

While trying to use `lookup` in 2nd level, getting an empty array instead of an object.

I have 3 collections, 
    1. `registration`
    2. `bus`
    3. `operator`

Here, `registration` contains `busId`, and the `bus` contains the `operatorId`.
I first populate the `bus` using the `busId` of `registration`. 
Then with the populated `bus` try to populate the `operator`.

Documents of **registration** collection:

```
{ "_id": "1", "busId": "1" }
{ "_id": "2", "busId": "2" }
```

Documents of **bus** collection:

```
{ "_id": "1", "operatorId": "1", "name": "bus 01" }
{ "_id": "2", "operatorId": "2", "name": "bus 02" }
```

Documents of **operator** collection:

```
{ "_id": "1", "name": "operator 01" }
{ "_id": "2", "name": "operator 02" }
```

My expected result:

```
[
  {
    _id: '1',
    busId: '1',
    busInfo: { _id: '1', operatorId: '1', name: 'bus 01' },
    operatorInfo:   { _id: '1', name: 'operator 01' }
  },
  {
    _id: '2',
    busId: '2',
    busInfo: { _id: '2', operatorId: '2', name: 'bus 02' },
    operatorInfo:   { '_id': '2', name: 'operator 02' }
  }
]
```

---

What I tried this far:

I am using the following aggregation:

```
db.collection('registration').aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'bus',
        localField: 'busId',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'busInfo'
      }
    },
    { $unwind: '$busInfo' },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'operator',
        localField: 'busInfo.operatorId',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'operatorInfo'
      }
    }
  ]);

And getting the empty operator list.
[
  {
    _id: '1',
    busId: '1',
    busInfo: { _id: '1', operatorId: '1', name: 'bus 01' },
    operatorInfo: []
  },
  {
    _id: '2',
    busId: '2',
    busInfo: { _id: '2', operatorId: '2', name: 'bus 02' },
    operatorInfo: []
  }
]
```

This result has the empty `operatorInfo` Array. But I need the `operatorInfo` object.

The first `lookup` is working fine. But after getting `bus` from the `busId`, I need to get the `operator` details of the `operatorId`. `operatorId` is inside the `bus`.

Comment: Use `busInfo.operatorId` instead of `busInfo.operator`.

Comment: Still getting empty `operatorInfo` array. I updated the question with `operatorId`. It was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

you should try
`localField: 'busInfo.operatorId` instead of
`localField: 'busInfo.operator`

Comment: Still getting empty `operatorInfo` array. I updated the question with `operatorId`. It was a typo.

Comment: try `operators` insted of operator